# Rfc2898DeriveBytes IterationCount purpose and best practices

Tags: .net, cryptography

What is the purpose of the `IterationCount` property of the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` class.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't shed too much light on it, but it does say that 1,000 is the recommended minimum.

If I'm going to set it to 1,000, why not 1,000,000 or 1,000,000,000?  Is there a reason behind the recommendation of 1,000, and is there a best practice for determining what value is right for each use case?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Rfc2898DeriveBytes` implements PBKDF2. This algorithm uses a salt and key stretching to create a relatively safe key from a password (normal length passwords are not that safe). To make it harder to brute force passwords it uses the iteration count (which is the linear cost added to create the key). The cost is identical for the legit user as well as for the attacker, but the attacker has to iterate through all possible passwords.

There is no standardized amount; basically you set it to such a value that is acceptable regarding CPU performance for you. 1000 is the recommended value within the standard, but that standard has been around for some years. Nowadays you should start with about 10K minimum<sup>**+**</sup>, anything above makes it harder for an attacker to find a password that generated the same "key".

<sup>**+**</sup> [EDIT] *Please lookup the current recommended number of iterations. Be warned that Moore's law is still in effect and that PBKDF2 itself does **not** use a exponential scale for the iteration count. Make sure the other password handling routines are secure as well (password strength feedback, maximum number of retries etc.).*

Obviously more important keys should be better protected. Note that generating a really secure password has more influence than adding iterations - using both a good password and high iteration count is of course best.

Comment: I understand that it's a vast subject (to put it mildly) and most likely outside the scope of this forum, but could you please briefly expound upon what happens during an iteration?  E.g. "During each iteration 'X' happens which makes the resulting key that much stronger."

Comment: @roryap To simplify, HASH(x) would be one iteration and HASH(HASH(HASH(x))) would be three iterations. PBKDF2 isn't quite that simple but there's the basic idea.

Comment: @ntoskrnl -- Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for.  And owlstead, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @roryap Thanks for the accept, removed link to standard because I must admit you need a bit of knowledge to know that function F in the standard is a HMAC, which relies on a hash. The general idea stays the same: the hash is iterated over itself + some more data.

Comment: HASH(HASH(HASH(x))) is a candidate for Rainbow Table.. Better use Rfc2898.

Comment: Yeah, above explanation ignores the salt. Use Rfc2889 with a random or at least unique salt for each password hash. You may have to store the salt for that, and I would recommend storing the iteration count as well so that it may be updated on password change.